# Selenium : Session not created Exception org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: android, selenium, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, testng-eclipse

Selenium is unable to create the session.

- Android version :- 7.1.1
- Selenium version :-2.50.1
- TestNG :-6.8
- Appium -3.3.0 :-2.50.1

Appium is unable to even install the app in the Mobile device but the same  code is working on the Motorola Device of the Android version 6.0. My chrome driver is also updated. Please help in solving the same.

Spring framework :-4.1.6.RELEASE

```
    Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'System info: host: 'Latitude-E5540', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-42-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)
at io.appium.java_client.A## Heading ##ppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:92)
at InstallApp.test(InstallApp.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error does gives some hint about whats wrong happening :

```
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'System info: host: 'Latitude-E5540', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-42-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
```

The error clearly mentions that the *AndroidDriver* is not getting detected back as in :

```
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *AndroidDriver* but the version and details are unknown to us.
- Your *Web Client* version and details is unknown to us.
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.0.1** of **2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700** which is almost **1.5 years** older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty ancient.
- Your *TestNG version* is **6.8** which is pretty old.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u131* , *Selenium Client v3.0.1* , *AndroidDriver* version, *TestNG* version and the *Web Client* version.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *TestNG* to  current levels **Version 6.14.2**.
- Upgrade *AndroidDriver* to  current levels.
- Upgrade *Web Client* to  current levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: How to know the android Driver version and the Web Client Version and how to update it ? I am trying it to run on the Redmi Note 5 pro and it is not working. Please help me in the same

Comment: @Nikhil_Coder _How to know the android Driver version and the Web Client Version_ should be part of your configuration/setup which I am not aware in _Redmi Note 5 pro_.